# Implementation of Dijkstra algorithm in GameMaker studio

Tags: python, algorithm, game-development, dijkstra, game-maker

I have been assigned a test task to implement the Dijkstra's algorithm in a 2D game. There are four objects: the start point, the end point, walls, and an object that should use the algorithm to find a path from the start point object to the end point object while avoiding obstacles (walls) and visually represent this path in the room. When dragging either the start or end point objects, the pathfinding should be recalculated, and the path should be updated accordingly. how to implement this algorithm in gamemaker?

I've already created all the objects, and the room is implemented (it took me 2 hours), but I can't figure out how to implement the algorithm. It's been my third day, and I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if you've provided a snippet of your attempts

Comment: *"how to implement this algorithm in gamemaker?"*: that is too broad a question. Please show your efforts and pinpoint where in your code you have a problem to take it a step further.

Comment: I have almost nothing in this regard. I have almost nothing in this regard. I’m not asking you to give me a solution to this task, that’s why I didn’t give all the details in the body of the question, I need to understand how it’s possible to implement the algorithm in a program

Comment: There are a lot of implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm on this site. There is also Wikipedia with a page dedicated to it. What is holding you back?

Comment: how to use it in a gamemaker?